# How to measure the two-photon detuning in 3-level system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, quantum-optics

If I have a 3-level system like:

[image]

Now, I want know how to measure the two-photon detuning in this system, and I known that Δ2 and Δ3 are the two- and on-photon detunings, like this paper said:

[image]

my questions are below:

1. How do other researchers measure these two parameters?
   They measure the beat frequency of probing light and controling light? Or they use an interferometer to measure the frequency of probing light?
2. Can anyone give me some examples for these parameter, like what is the approximate magnitude of two-photon detuning，if you have any paper or publication about that?

Comment: it would be useful to have the reference to the original text...